# Error loading background in PrestaShop when using homemodalwindow module

Tags: jquery, fancybox, prestashop

When using the homemodalwindow popup module, there is an object which cant load in the background and all the background fails to load. Aparently the error is around here according to Google Chrome

```
<div class="fancybox-overlay fancybox-overlay-fixed" style="width: auto; height: auto; display: block;">
...
<div class="fancybox-inner" style="overflow: hidden; width: 500px; height: 100px;">

-----------
"Error: Failed to execute 'webkitMatchesSelector' on 'Element': ':hidden' is not a valid selector.
    at Function.m.matchesSelector (../TiendaN/js/jquery/jquery-1.7.2.min.js:3:25810)
```

Comment: I am curious - did you figure this one out?  I am running across a similar issue.

Comment: honestly I cant remember, and Im not using it now. Usually when I find the error I post back the answer so I guess no

Answer (score 0):

I maybe say something stupid but, did you tried to use a newer version of jquery (more than 1.7)?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue!  I can not point to one thing that fixed it as I had a few issues going on.  Here is the list of things that I did and eventually it was fixed for me:

1. I had upgraded [angularjs](/questions/tagged/angularjs) to 1.2.x.
2. After I received the same error.
3. Upgraded to [jquery](/questions/tagged/jquery) 1.11.x **with the migration plugin**!
4. Added 'ngRoute' & 'ngSanitize' modules to my app as it was separated out with the Angular upgrade.
5. Temporarily removed [parsley](/questions/tagged/parsley).

I will try to post any more updates, just in case this would help someone else out.

Thanks!