# Mootools and JQuery conflict any other way to make it work together other than jQuery.noConflict()?

Tags: jquery, mootools

I was trying to include a popup window made using Mootools library into another software which uses JQuery. Thing is, the other software has a gazillion lines which includes JQuery and it would be better not to change everywhere those lines, but to find another solution or workaround to make both codes JQuery and Mootools work together, either changing the Mootools code which is smaller or another workaround?

Greetings

Comment: You're almost certainly better off using one of the zillions of popup window libraries for jQuery instead, rather than adding an entire general-purpose DOM manipulation library into an app that already has one, just for popups.

Comment: also, you really need a few things. versions of mootools and jquery and order of loading of the script tags.

Comment: Actually I looked for another window library other than JQuery, because JQuery's triggering a load error in the background, another problem I'm carrying

Comment: this problem  I couldnt solve http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22404821/error-loading-background-in-prestashop-when-using-homemodalwindow-module

Comment: You need to post some code for us to help. You could do everything with just Mootools probably.